# Update Laravel One-to-One Relation using dot notation in one request

Tags: laravel

I have two related models

```php
// User
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne( Profile::class );
}

// Profile
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo( User::class );
}
```

and I want update them both in one request so I have this form (simplified)

```
<input name="nickname">
<input name="profile[about]">
```

`nickname` field related to User model while `profile.about` - to Profile.

In my controller method I have this

```php
public function update( User $user, UpdateRequest $request )
{
    $user->update( $request->validated() );
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Validated data contains

```
[
  'nickname' => 'some name',
  'profile' => [
    'about' => 'some text'
  ]
]
```

I hoped `profile.about` field would update about column of profile table but it is not. Is it possible to update Profile model using this validated data without calling next `$user->profile->update( $request->validated('profile') );`?

Comment: maybe, just maybe, if you have this in you user controller getProfileAttribute, returning the relation ... but honestly, that's no a good ideia at all

Answer (score 0):

For your given relationships, you can create a UserRequest class for validate data, more information
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation

The command `php artisan make:request UserRequest` will create UserRequest class in `App\Http\Request` namespace, then you must define your validation rules:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UserRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize() {
        return true; // YOU WILL BE AUTHORIZE ALL REQUESTS
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nickname' => 'required',
            'profile.about' => 'required' //Nested array elements are validated with dot syntax
            // Other rules you need
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'nickname.required' => 'Custom validation message for rule required',
            'profile.about.required' => 'Custom validation message for rule required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Then you must define your controller update method like so:

```php
public function update( User $user, UserRequest $request )
{
    // At this point your data is valid, if not, 422 error will be returned with custom messages defined
    $inputs = $request->all();
    $user->update( $inputs );
    $user->profile()->update($inputs['profile'])
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: Hi, Daniel! Thanks but that is not what am I asking for. I want to know is there elegant way to deal with request data and avoid calling update again like `$user->profile()->update($inputs['profile']);`. I hope there is some Laravel way of doing this I don't know